# replace function doesn't work with '$' symbol

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace('$@test', '$@test', '111111111111111')" />
```

how to make this work?

If I try to not using '$' sign everything works

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace('$@test', '@test', '111111111111111')" />
```

Comment: Please define "works" / "doesn't work". What is the actual behavior you're seeing (the "doesn't work" behavior), and how does it differ from the behavior you want/expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<xsl:value-of select="replace('$@test', '\$@test', '111111111111111')" />`, assuming you want to treat the dollar sign literally. As it is a meta character in the regular expression language used to match the end of a string or a line to treat it literally you need to escape it.

Comment: @Vishnu, the original question is about XSLT 2.0. If you want to use XSLT 2.0 with C# then you need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor available for .NET, like the .NET version of Saxon 9 or like XmlPrime. If you need help using regular expressions in C# then post a question and tag it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

For quick reference you may refer http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/06/04/tr.html